# Rails console compare model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

Is there a way to compare two instances of model like

Model.compare_by_name("model1", "model2") which would list the differing column fields

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::Diff`](https://github.com/tim/activerecord-diff) if you want a mapping of all the fields that differ and their values.

```
alice = User.create(:name => 'alice', :email_address => 'alice@example.org')
bob = User.create(:name => 'bob', :email_address => 'bob@example.org')    
alice.diff?(bob)  # => true
alice.diff(bob)  # => {:name => ['alice', 'bob'], :email_address => ['alice@example.org', 'bob@example.org']}
alice.diff({:name => 'eve'})  # => {:name => ['alice', 'eve']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using a library or  defining a custom method, you can easily get a diff between two models.

For instance,

```
a = Foo.first
b = Foo.second

a.attributes = b.attributes

a.changes #=> {"id" => [1,2] }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard comparator for this. The standard ActiveModel comparator:

```
Returns true if comparison_object is the same exact object, or comparison_object is of the same type and self has an ID and it is equal to comparison_object.id.
```

You can write your own by using Hash#diff from activesupport. Something like the following should hopefully get you started:

```
def Model.compare_by_name(model1, model2)
  find_by_name(model1).attributes.diff(find_by_name(model2).attributes)
end
```